# Matlab fast gpuArray visualization

Tags: image, matlab, gpu, heatmap

The task is simple, you are processing a gpuArray of a descent size, say 2048x2048, inside a for loop and you want to visualize it by generating an image plot (or heat map) in real time.

```
A=gpuArray(...);
for i=nFrames
    A= ... ;
    imagesc(A);
    drawnow;
end
```

Now the problem is that you get a very low framerate (<10 fps) when using imagesc() or imshow() even though the processing does not take that long. If you want to set 'CData' for an image handle declared since the beginning, you are forced to move the array into the CPU memory which is time expensive and defeats the purpose.

Is there any specific tool useful to accelerate visualization of gpuArrays?

I've watched a webinar on solving PDEs with the GPU where the presenter has a code that does this in real time. You can watch the video to get the exact idea of what I'm looking for.

http://www.mathworks.com/videos/gpu-computing-with-matlab-81840.html?form_seq=conf882&elqsid=1435085269409&potential_use=Student&country_code=US

Comment: once upon a time you could use `imagesc` in jacket to do this in real time...  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacket_%28software%29 , but that is no longer supported. So if you can get jacket installed with your matlab you're set.